# Not able to established more than 65532 TCP/IP Socket Connection in windows 10 after setting -DFD_SETSIZE to 110K

Tags: windows-10, socket

I'm not able to establish more than 65532 TCP/IP Socket Connection on Windows 10.

After 65532 TCP/IP Socket Connections in Windows 10, getting Socket Error 10055 - No Buffer Space Available.

WSAGetLastError() is returning Error 10055 - No Buffer Space Available.

Can more than 65532 TCP/IP Socket Connections be established on Windows? If so, how can this be achieved?
In Non-windows we can set FD limit.

I have modified the registry:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \System \CurrentControlSet \Services \Tcpip \Parameters]
TcpNumConnections = 0x00fffffe (Default = 16,777,214)

MaxUserPort = 5000 (Default = 5000, Max = 65534)

TcpMaxDataRetransmissions = 5

TcpTimedWaitDelay = 30

TcpWindowSize = 64512

Answer (score 0):

Winsock or Windows Sockets is a technical specification that defines how Windows network software should access network services.

I would suggest you to try the step below and check if it helps.

Step 1: Reset Winsock

```
Press Windows + X, Choose Command prompt (admin).

Click yes on User Account Control prompt .

Type netsh Winsock reset in the prompt and press enter.
```

This command will reset the Winsock, if you get any error message while resetting provide us the details.

Step 2: Reset TCP/IP

How to reset TCP/IP by using the NetShell utility

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357?wa=wsignin1.0

Note: This link also applies to Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Resetting TCP/IP will reset the IP configuration settings and fix internet connection issues.

Comment: Thank you Roger. But above solution is not working. I have set -DFD_SETSIZE to 110K while compiling the server application.